# Is there a way to set project metadata in GCP deployment manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

We are using GCP Deployment manager for our infrastructure release. We need to have a shared place that could be accessible from all groups(e.g. project metadata). I think it should be great if we could have it as a part of our infrastructure as code, so we could connect it with all the groups.
I think that for now there is no such [resource](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types) in GCP deployment manager, but I also would not like to have some separate script that will do this update out of the pattern.
Can someone help with this? what is the best way to store common metadata in the cloud, and if the cloud could not provide the right tool, how can we solve this issue in a clear/nice way?

Answer (score 1):

Setting project wide metadata is done using the [compute.v1.projects](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects) API which is not supported for DM. You can view a list of the supported resources for DM [here](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types).
You may want to suggest support for this resource through a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a yaml config file and its template for you:

The project.yaml configuration :

```
# Set project metadata

imports:
- path: project.jinja

resources:
- name: project
  type: project.jinja
  properties:
    key: 'abcd'
    value: 1234
```

And the project.jinja template:

```
{#
Template: Set Project Metadata
#}

resources:
- name: data
  action: gcp-types/compute-v1:compute.projects.setCommonInstanceMetadata
  metadata:
    runtimePolicy:
    - UPDATE_ON_CHANGE
  properties:
    items:
      - key: {{ properties["key"] }}
        value: {{ properties["value"] }}
```

Comment: Please refer to [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and provide some details in your answer.

Comment: No, I will not.